# What could cause sIFR text to display differently on different systems?

Tags: sifr, sifr3

There's a website I built a few years ago using sIFR. Nothing's really changed on it at all in terms of styling — just some content added/removed edited via XML.

The site owner emailed me today asking why suddenly some of the text (rendered in sIFR3) is breaking like this:

[image: problem with sIFR rendering]

I could not reproduce this on *any* of my browsers. It was happening to him in both FF and Safari (Mac). We are using the same browser versions on the same OS.  He was on OS X 10.6.6 but upgraded to 10.6.7 while were trying to narrow down what would cause it.  He still got the "incorrect" version.  I downgraded my Flash plugins to the exact version he had on his computer, and I still had the "correct" version.  He checked all the other computers at his office, and *they* all rendered it correctly as well.

So in two environments where all of these things were identical:

- Operating system and version
- Browser version
- Flash player/plugin version

What other possibilities could be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: Does sIFR inherit the font scaling? Try getting the site owner to reset the font/page zoom (should be something like Cmd+0).

Comment: I actually thought of that, but if you look at the screen shots, there is no difference in scaling. I had even overlaid the two shots to double check.  In addition, both browser he experienced this in do full page zooms by default, and when you select "zoom text only" the sIFR text is not affected (only the plain ol' html text zooms).

Comment: Interesting. For the record, it looks fine for me too in Chrome 11 on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I had wrapping text letters in IE but not FF -- but I found the solution. I used forceSingleLine: true; in my sIFR.replace styles in sifr-config.jsp. Below is an example of it being used.

sIFR.replace(test, {
  selector: 'h1',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #cccccc; width: 100%; text-align: left; letter-spacing:1;}',
  wmode: 'transparent',
  forceSingleLine: true;
});

I found the answer here:
http://www.conetrees.com/2009/10/quickposts/fixing-the-sifr-3-text-wrap-issue/

Comment: I've used that before — I'm not sure why I didn't think of it in this istance.  I'll give it a shot.  It's just bizarre that, if it had to do with any script/style settings, that it wouldn't be doing the same thing on other peoples systems with the same OS, flash and browser versions.